# Configure management tool to auto-configure by reading config file

Tags: linux, chef, configuration-management, chef-solo, autoconfiguration

The use-case is as given below:

The user has a `Flat File` in his Linux system. This file is a human readable/editable file which contains the configurations for all the needed components of his application running on the system. For example, the user has an application 'APP' which has components like 'A' , 'B' and 'C'. and the 'Flat File' is housing the configuration for 'A' , 'B' and 'C'  as follows:

```
A
Parameter1: value1
Parameter2: value2
Parameter3: value3
..
..

B
Parameter1: value1
Parameter2: value2
Parameter3: value3
..
..

C
Parameter1: value1
Parameter2: value2
Parameter3: value3
..
..
```

The user is expecting a configuration utility to read this file and configure the components A, B and C appropriately using the REST APIs associated with the  components when the application starts.

Is the configuration tool like `Chef` capable of doing the above scenario?  Otherwise, recommend any other open source tools capable of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Open-ended questions like this are generally discouraged but sure, Chef can probably handle this a little more easily than Ansible, Salt, or Puppet because you have normal Ruby available more directly but any of the four could do it it. You would have to write a parser in Ruby or Python and some code to generate the required HTTP requests.